# How to get a specific value from vue.js asp.net-core-mvc result set

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, vue.js

I've made an implementation of vue.js in an .net-core mvc project which will return data from a controller. So let's say that the result is:

```
[{"id":1,"uniqueStr":"string1","ttlValue":"something","hlpValue":"something2"},{"id":2,"uniqueStr":"string2","ttlValue":"something","hlpValue":"something2"}]
```

I can get the row value with a snippet like:

```
{{ data[0] }}
```

So I have two things remaining. The situation is, I need the rows on one page without a loop. So my question would be:

How can I get the "ttlValue" of the row where the "uniqueStr" would be "string2".

I thinking something in the line of but that obviously doesn't function:
{{ data[0][1] }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with a computed value, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2194/). If you need to pass a parameter, you can use a method instead, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2198/).

I'm not sure what you meant with **without a loop** though. My solution loops through the object with `.filter` and with your current data structure, it's not really doable more directly.

Comment: Ah I see, that is indeed a method. I'll see if I can adjust specificValue() to accept a variable then it would be perfect

Comment: I added an example with passing a parameter - the code is nearly identical, you just use `methods` instead of `computed`.